# how can I make a tkinter variable set as random int change when iterating through for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning python and attempting to make a die rolling app. It is mostly functional, but this little bit of code isn't functioning right.

The goal of the program is to take a user input for the number of dice to roll and the number of faces on the dice, and output random numbers for each die, within the range(number of faces)

```
def die_count(*args):
    x = 0
    count = int(total.get())
    faces = int(sides.get())
    for i in range(count):
        die_value.set(random.randint(1, faces))
        ttk.Label(frame, textvariable = die_value).grid(row = 3, column = x)
        x = x + 1
```

I'm just learning tkinter as well, so possibly there is some arcane behavior of *.set()* that I have yet to learn...
I would expect this code to iterate through the loop *count* times, reassigning *die_value* every time. It loops correctly, but the die_value remains the same in each label.

an example output for the inputs total = 3 and faces = 6, would be 5 5 5, and on a rerun, 3 3 3, or any other numbers in the range repeated "total" number of times.

The range for the outputs is correct, in that it never exceeds the bounds of the value input for sides. The individual values though, are supposed to be different from one another, and I'm not sure whats causing them not to be.

below is the entire code (I know its a hot mess, but I want to get it working, then make it pretty)

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("die roll")
window.geometry("500x500")


def die_count(*args):
    x = 0
    count = int(total.get())
    faces = int(sides.get())
    for i in range(count):
        die_value.set(random.randint(1, faces))
        ttk.Label(frame, textvariable = die_value).grid(row = 3, column = x)
        x = x + 1

die_value = IntVar()
total = IntVar()
sides = IntVar()

ttk.Label(window, text='how many dice would \n you like to roll?',borderwidth=1).grid(row=0,column=0)

ttk.Entry(window,textvariable=total).grid(row=0,column=1)

ttk.Label(window, text='how many sides \n should the dice have?',borderwidth=1).grid(row=1,column=0)

ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=sides).grid(row=1,column=1)

ttk.Button(window, text="Roll", command = die_count).grid(row = 2,column=0)

frame = ttk.Frame(window).grid(row=2, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: In terms of coding style, a function named `die_roll` should probably take the `count` and `faces` as arguments and then return some integer or list, rather than manipulate any external `tkinter` objects.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what your program should do. Please describe accurately and give a more complete example.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, are you suggesting that I create one function to handle the assignment of the die_values, then another to handle the tkinter object manipulation? Or is there a different way to handle the addition of objects dynamically? I added a program description, and some more clarification on the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
def die_count(*args):
    x = 0
    count = int(total.get())
    faces = int(sides.get())
    for i in range(count):
        ttk.Label(frame, text = random.randint(1, faces)).grid(row = 3, column = x)
        x += 1
```

I have changed textvariable to text, because it would "bind" the `textvariable`, so every time you changed the `textvariable`, it would change the value (which is why they all ended up with the value of the last roll). With `text`, this does not occur.

Comment: Thank you so much! your explanation is really helpful, because I didn't understand that binding was happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to only have one instance of `die_value`. I assume your Labels need one each:

```
    for i in range(count):
        die_value = IntVar()
        die_value.set(random.randint(1, faces))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So to be clear, every time die_value = IntVar() is invoked, it creates a new instance?

Comment: Yes, so that each `IntVar()` created holds onto its own value from `random.randint(1, faces)`, rather than `die_value.set(...)` overwriting the value each time.

Comment: Ohhhh that makes sense. I wasn't thinking of IntVar() as a class. Noob mistake I suppose.